# Auto-generate a try catch block in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Anyone know if there is a keystroke shortcut or option to autogenerate a try/catch block around a statement in Visual Studio 2010? I can see what exceptions are thrown if I look at the overlay documentation when I hover over a statement. I'd like to right click -> generate try/catch, as it would save a lot of time in handling all possible cases.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### Using the mouse

1. Mark your code
2. Right-click
3. Select `Surround with...`
4. Double-click `try`

### Using the keyboard #1

1. Mark your code using <kbd>Shift</kbd>,
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, or whatever works for you
2. Press [`Menu key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) / [`Application key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) (alternatively <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>)
3. Type <kbd>S</kbd>
4. Type <kbd>T</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>

### Using the keyboard #2 *(as [perlox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362698/perlox) and [Fredrik Norlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178322/fredrik-norlin) points out)*

1. Mark your code using <kbd>Shift</kbd>,
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, or whatever works for you
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
3. Type <kbd>T</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: But this isn't the full answer!

OP wanted all possible exception cases for a chosen piece of code to be handled in a snippet, not one.

Answer (score 43):

type `try` then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>

2 x <kbd>Tab</kbd> activates a code snippet.

type `tryf` , <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> to activate the `try..finally` block instead

Comment: Is there any way to add try, catch, finally?

Comment: well, sure :-) you could always a) download additional code snippets, b) write your own code snippets, it's easy!

Comment: Life saver :)) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to remove your fingers from the keyboard, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That's basically what he said, but without using the mouse.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hf704tz%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: `+1` I didn't think of the actual keyboard shortcuts

Comment: +1 for this answer. For newer versions of visual studio, I located the shortcuts under ```Edit``` --> ```IntelliSense``` --> ```Surround With...```, which has the same keyboard shortcuts that you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I use CodeRush from DevExpress. I can use the key strokes "TC" to generate. It works with C# too.

```
    Try

                Catch ex As Exception
                    dmPrgm_Err(Err, ex)
                End Try
```

I then can use TSC for a Try SQL Catch with custom message boxes.

```
            Try

                Catch ex As SqlException
                    dmSQLErr(ex)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    dmPrgm_Err(Err, ex)
                End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a visualstudio 2017 extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ZTransform.TryCatch

If you want to use it with VS2019: download, change extension to zip, unzip, follow these instructions https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/, zip, rename to .vsix and install.