# How to surround code blocks with try/catch in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I know that Visual Studio has some tools for fast surrounding by code snippets, for example how to do more faster try/catch code blocks. but I can't find a hotkey combination to do this. Who knows the hotkey combination for try/catch?

Comment: type "try" then tap Tab,Tab

Comment: @sa_ddam213: That doesn't surround the currently selected code with try catch.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969288/auto-generate-a-try-catch-block-in-visual-studio-2010>

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Press "Ctrl + K, S" and then in drop down menu double click "try" - it's a "try-catch" template.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Select the code first and then press `Ctrl+K,S`

Comment: Here's a rather inappropriate tip to help remember this shortcut: KS (kamasutra) is a rather popular condom brand in India. Whenever, you need to "surround" something...ahem..you just use ctrl + K,S

Comment: Although in spirit correct its `ctrl + K, ctrl+S` if you do that combination VS would not recognize it. This is more to the point:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13602070/1242782)

Comment: A more appropriate way to remember this shortcut is that it takes you to the *K*eyboard *S*hortcuts

Comment: @Habib,  what if i want to add try-catch directly without selecting any line, like before typing some code, is there any short cut in this case??

Comment: Vivek Thummar, the same shortcut works

Comment: This does not seem to work in python files

Answer (score 32):

Try Ctrl + K, Ctrl + S.
[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hf704tz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: if i could double plus 1 you i could!!
i tried the `ctrl + K, S` and always lost my code, I kept banging my head until I read you post....

Comment: Ctrl + k, Ctrl + s worked in my VS2022, rather than Ctrl + k, s

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl + K, followed by CTRL + S
Type T
Press Enter or Tab

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, select the code that you want to surround -> press cmd+shift+P, type: surround with, Select a snippet: try-catch