# How to Add try catch Block Automatically in Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to add try catch block automatically when i add new function from  specific Control Events in Visual studio 2005 and above.

Comment: If that was a universally sensible thing to do, it would be built in already. You should only be writing `catch` blocks for specific exceptions at points at which you have a strategy for dealing with the specific error and continuing. Everything else should be left to the unhandled exception handler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-generate a try catch block in visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969288/auto-generate-a-try-catch-block-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: you needed to create code snippet

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is create [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) for each of the functions you want the try-catch blocks to be created for, if you use the snippet to add the function it will include whatever code you put in the template (which can include your try-catch block and whatever logging/error handling you want to happen).

Answer (score -1):

Like Scott Chamberlain wrote, you can do that using code snippets, one thing Is important to say is, using a try catch statement should be the last resort, as catching an exception and raising it takes a long time and **WILL** hurt performance.

If you have any way to check and maintain a problem before it will throw an exception, do that.

Comment: -1: usually performance won't matter, and even when it does matter, there are some rare cases where the try-catch form performs better (when the exception is very rare and avoiding the check for the common case becomes noticeable)