# C# Custom annotation to wrap code with try/catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, annotations, customization

I am looking for explanation how to create custom annotation, that i can put anywhere in my code and on compilation it will wrap code block followed by this annotation, with try and catch. 
Its ok if this solution will be only available for methods.
All examples i read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56.aspx), does not give me direction where to find desired solution.

Comment: You can't do this with attributes. You can't do this with no built in language or compiler support either. This would require a post compile rewriter or some such.

Comment: Not the answer to the question but may be helpful: VS Shortcuts for wrapping code in a try catch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969288/auto-generate-a-try-catch-block-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

Attributes just decorate classes and methods. You need to look for **AOP** (Aspect Oriented Programming) for better directions.

You can start with this [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1305/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-csharp-using-solid)